# Abrir DIV após clicar em um Botão com Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css3

Gostaria de saber como criar, seja em CSS3, Javascript ou Jquery, um botão que, ao clicá-lo, seja revelado uma DIV sobre ele, e que seja aberta uma nova página com target _blank.

Já pesquisei bastente, achei algumas coisas, mas nada concreto. É claro que, se possível, gostaria de algo que funcionasse em todos os navegadores.

--

**Atualização**

O que desejo se encaixa na resposta do Diego, mas uma coisa que esqueci de citar na pergunta, é se é possível abrir o link da página sem sair da janela atual.

Comment: Não conheço um método de utilizar o target, sem sair da janela atual. Acho que é questão para outra pergunta.

Answer (score 6):

Sua pergunta é muita ampla e pode ser resolvida de diversas formas. Tente sempre postar parte do código que está trabalhando para podemos melhor te ajudar.

Darei algumas diretrizes.

### HTML

O HTML deve ser bem simples. Algo tipo:

```
<button>Clique aqui</button>
<div id="divId" class="hidden"></div>
```

### CSS

O CSS deve conter o posicionamento do `div` para que ele fique em cima do botão. Não coloquei esses estilos aqui. Implemente por conta própria do jeito que for conveniente. Adicionei apenas o estilo que esconde o `div`.

```
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

### JQuery

O seguinte código efetua a ação que você procura.

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('#divId').show(); // aparece o div
    window.open(seulink,'_blank'); // abre nova janela
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 6):

### HTML

```
<div id="escondido">
    Eu irei aparecer
</div>
<a href="http://google.com.br" target="_blank" id="Clique">Clique aqui</a>
```

### CSS

```
#escondido{
    display:none;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$( "#Clique" ).click(function() {
  $("#escondido").css("display","block");
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qogtzk6/)