# Preciso deixar uma <div> invisível até clicar nela para abrir

Tags: html5, css3

Olá, preciso deixar uma `<div>` invisível até eu clicar nela para abrir.

Ela será usada como estatística para cada pessoa, então somente eu clicando no nome da pessoa ela iria abrir essa div abaixo do nome da pessoa.

Seria quase igual aos comentários do facebook, que só quando clicar eles aparecem.

Comment: Acho que você só precisa programar um evento em javascript, tem esse post na própria comunidade, dá uma olhada pra ver se te ajuda :) Link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40536/abrir-div-ap%C3%B3s-clicar-em-um-bot%C3%A3o-com-link

Comment: Como esconder/mostrar uma div em HTML?: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html